# Doxygen Comments check for differences

Tags: c++, comments, qt-creator, doxygen

I am using qtcreator on linux and am searching for a way to update the Doxygen comments in the c++ code I am working with.
I like to be notified if somebody changed a signature when the documentation is not matching anymore whats in the code. What tool is able to automatically check for differences between signature and doxycomments, and preferable is able of adding empty /param for every missing parameter?

Comment: Doesn't doxygen give you a warning when a number of orguments is not documented (EXTRACT_ALL should be off)?

Comment: @albert: Thanks, you are right, I haven't noticed. I used EXTRACT_ALL=YES. It displays the missing parameters, but it would be nice to see them highlighted in qtcreator, if somebody knows ... would be awesome